# Show that this is a valid probability density function

Tags: probability, statistics

[image: the PMF in question]

I know how to answer this when there is only one function in the piecewise function, but having two is confusing me. The criteria for a valid PDF are:

1. $f(x) \geq 0 $ for all x
2. $\sum f(x) = 1$

It's easy to prove or disprove when there's just one function in the piecewise function (as in one function for the interval [a,b] and then $0$ otherwise) but I can't figure out how to do this with two functions.

I tried doing the sums of the two functions added together but I get a 2 instead of 1, and given how many parts there are to this question, I'm presuming I've done it wrong and that this is indeed a valid PDF. I also tried proving them separately and the second is greater than 1 and the first is less than 1, so that's obviously not correct.

Can anybody help me figure this out? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a density you want to integrate rather than sum, i.e. have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx =1$$

so here you need to show $$\int_{-\infty}^{0} 0 \, dx +\int_{0}^{1} \tfrac2{29}(x+5) \, dx +\int_{1}^{2} \tfrac{12}{29}x \, dx +\int_2^{\infty} 0 \, dx=1.$$

This does indeed give $1$, but you should check it.  Most of the rest is also integration.

Comment: Ah okay that makes more sense. Thank you very much for your help!